# Error creating tun device (Invalid argument)

Tags: c, linux, networking

I'm referencing the example here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt (which is quite old), but the link here suggests that the same thing should work as well: (http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/). 
I'm finding very little in the way of up-to-date documentation otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>  
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>

int main(void) {
    char *clonedev = "/dev/net/tun"; 
    int fd, err;
    char * dev_name = "tun0";
    struct ifreq ifr;
   if( (fd = open(clonedev, O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
        exit(1);
   }
   memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
   strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev_name, IFNAMSIZ);

   printf("Opened %s \n", ifr.ifr_name);
    if( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr)) < 0 ) {
        printf("Failed to creat tun device (errno is %d)\n",
             errno);
        perror("ioctl");
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
   }
   printf("device created");
}
```

Output:

```
Opened tun0 
Failed to creat tun device (errno is 22)
ioctl: Invalid argument
```

---

edit: Grepping OpenVPN source code shows the same usage:

```
src/openvpn/tun.c:1681:      if (ioctl (tt->fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr) < 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not having something like this, which both your links do have:

```
ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;
```

Seems like a very reasonable way of getting an invalid argument error.

Answer (score 0):

You missed this line in the example

```
ifr.ifr_flags = flags;   /* IFF_TUN or IFF_TAP, plus maybe IFF_NO_PI */
```

So, missing this before ioctl()

```
ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;
```

or

```
ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP;
```